# Outlier detection, excluding outliers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, outliers, sql-server-2017

I want to detect outliers (greater than 20x stddev deviation from the average) but I don't want to have the more than 3x outliers affecting the average. I came up with this:

```
SELECT d.* FROM
(
    SELECT 
     d.*,
     (amount - avg(amount_excl_3z) OVER(PARTITION BY productid)) / NULLIF(STDEV(amount_excl_3z) OVER(PARTITION BY productid), 0) AS zscore_ex
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            d.*,
            --when the amount zscore is 3x, null the amount else provide
            CASE WHEN ABS(amount - avg(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY productid)) / NULLIF(STDEV(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY productid), 0) > 3 
            THEN NULL ELSE amount END AS amount_excl_3z
        FROM sales d 
        WHERE --the past year's sales of product 1, but one day I will consider all prods hence why i left the partitions in
          timestamp > GETUTCDATE()-365.0 AND 
          productid = 1
    ) d
) d
WHERE e.zscore_ex > 20
ORDER BY amount desc
```

The concern with the data is that if too many outliers occur they will drastically affect the average - there might be 1000 occurrences of a product with an amount of 1, and then 5 occurrences of a product amount of 20,000.. I don't want the 20,000 to influence the average.. I don't really want 50 occurrences of 20,000 to influence the average.. 500 occurrences though, that would be OK/represent a new norm..

The way I'm thus considering doing this is to strip out low occurrences of massive outliers. If they start occurring frequently enough that they affect the average enough to come into range, then I'll start including them..

The query above is my best stab at "outlier detection that tries to exclude low numbers of wild outliers from having too much of an impact" - is there any other facility in SQL server that I can leverage more effectively for this algorithm? Perhaps some analytic query that can indicate where on a distribution curve a point lies? I looked at PERCENT_RANK, CUME_DIST, PERCENTILE_CONT/DISC, NTILE, but they seemed to be more linear in the distribution of the output than doing a zscore..

Comment: Based on your normal data distribution, how close is your median value to your average value? If they are usually close, you could use your median as the starting point for your outlier calculations.